# Jupyter notebook server running but not opening in a browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

I have install miniconda and jupyter on windows through wsl.
Although the server starts, i am unable to open the same in the browser.
Thus i cannot access the started jupyter notebook.

Attaching the screenshots for the same.
[Successful server started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9DCA.png)

[Unable to open in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Si1G.png)

I tried opening the notebook from the runtime .html file, using "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".
I also tried running the notebook using the command "jupyter-notebook" whose alias i defined in bashrc.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your question.  Please consider posting the text of errors as well as logs in `code blocks` rather than screenshots.  It makes it easier to read inline, helps search engines find the question in the future if others have the same problem, and allows others to copy/paste if it helps them answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63452108/get-err-connection-refused-accessing-django-running-on-wsl2-from-windows-but-can/63455770#63455770) which I previously answered.  While that was for Django and yours is about Jupyter, I have a feeling it's the same root issue.

If you do a `python3 -m http.server 3001`, can you access it from Windows at http://localhost:3001?  If not, then it's probably the port forwarding problem rather than anything specific to Jupyter.

The consensus of those that commented on my answer seemed to be that `wsl --shutdown` was the best solution.  I can say that, since then, even though I have Fast Startup disabled, I've seen the problem and had to do a `wsl --shutdown` and restart to resolve.