# Connecting to PostgreSQL on WSL

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to connect to PostgreSQL server running in WSL from pgAdmin running in Windows? If you specify localhost and port 5432, the error appears:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D / 10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (:: 1) and accepting
TCP / IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D / 10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP / IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: WSL1 or WSL2?  If WSL2, try `python3 -m http.server 8087` and then browse to `localhost:8087` in Windows.  Does that work?  If not, you are likely running into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66266211/11810933).

Answer (score 4):

i got the same issue with a Ubuntu WSL2 and here is how i solved it :

- in wsl get your local ip address (`ip addr` and look for the adress in `eth0` section after `inet`.). for me it was `172.18.117.222/20`.
- in the pg_hba.conf add a mask line in the IPv4 section to allow connection through the local IP address :
  `host    all             all             172.18.117.222/20       md5`
- restart the postgresql server.
- connect in PgAdmin using `172.18.117.222` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: This works, but unfortunately WSL generates a new IP address on every restart, meaning you have to re-register the server in pgAdmin every time. Quite a bummer!

Comment: @mchristos now you can assign a static IP to WSL to avoid that issue: https://gist.github.com/wllmsash/1636b86eed45e4024fb9b7ecd25378ce

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer, you may also need to change the `postgresql.conf` file to allow sql to listen on non-local port.

For that you need to edit `postgresql.conf` and change `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'`

Then restart postgresql on wsl with `sudo service postgresql restart`