# PgAdmin unable to connect to server running on WSL2

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, wsl-2

I have a postgres server running on WSL2 and I am accessing it via PgAdmin (v5 and v4). Until today everything worked fine, but now I keep getting an error message when trying to connect from PgAdmin:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

These are the server settings in PgAdmin:

```
Host name/address: 127.0.0.1
Port: 5432
```

I have checked that postgres is running on port 5432 in WSL2 and `listen_adresses` is set to `'*'` in `postgresql.conf`

The weirdest part is that I have a NestJS app connected to the same database and it works **without any errors**, also donwloaded a VS Code extension that can establish connection to a postgres server and connected successfully with the credentials listed above.

So what could the problem be? Is PgAdmin bugging out?

EDIT: Restarted WSL2 and it works...

Comment: Sounds like you may have run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455770/11810933).  Two possible causes for it - Hibernation will trigger it, as will a shutdown when Windows Fast Startup is enabled.  As you've found, a `wsl --shutdown` seems to be needed to restore the localhost forwarding to the right state.