# Connecting to server on WSL2 from Windows host doesn't work

Tags: networking, windows-10, quarkus, wsl-2

#### Update 1

If I package the code as a Docker image & run it, the curl commands work from inside WSL2 **and** from the Windows command line, so this is a Quarkus-specific issue.

### Original

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on WSL2 on my Windows Home laptop.

Following the [Quarkus Getting Started](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started) example (just up to step 5: *Running the application*), I have the code (server) running on my WSL2 `bash` command line, & calling it with `curl` gives the expected output:

```
user@computer:/path$ curl -w '\n' http://localhost:8080/hello
Hello RESTEasy
```

**However,** I can't access that server from the host Windows computer's command line (`cmd`):

```
C:\Users\username>curl -w "\n" http://localhost:8080/hello

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

Unlike this [WSL 2 Networking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCK3easuYm4) video, I am not trying to access the running server from outside my Windows host. I can't even reach the server running inside WSL2 Ubuntu from the Windows host.

Nonetheless, I tried this slightly modified script [from an issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150):

```
#$remoteport = bash.exe -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '"
$remoteport = bash.exe -c "ip addr | grep -Ee 'inet.*eth0'"

$found = $remoteport -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if( $found ){
  $remoteport = $matches[0];
} else{
  echo "The Script Exited, the ip address of WSL 2 cannot be found";
  exit;
}

#[Ports]

#All the ports you want to forward separated by coma
$ports=@(8080);


#[Static ip]
#You can change the addr to your ip config to listen to a specific address
$addr='0.0.0.0';
$ports_a = $ports -join ",";


#Remove Firewall Exception Rules
iex "Remove-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL2-Firewall-Unlock' ";

#adding Exception Rules for inbound and outbound Rules
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL2-Firewall-Unlock' -Direction Outbound -LocalPort $ports_a -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL2-Firewall-Unlock' -Direction Inbound -LocalPort $ports_a -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $ports.length; $i++ ){
  $port = $ports[$i];
  iex "netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr";
  iex "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr connectport=$port connectaddress=$remoteport";
}
```

The script ran fine after some settings changes, but I still couldn't reach the server running on WSL2. Couldn't reach it via browser (Vivaldi) either (see screenshot).

[image: Can't reach WSL2 server via browser either]

In desperation I tried the following, but none worked:

```
C:\Users\username>curl -w "\n" http://192.168.1.6:8080/hello

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset

C:\Users\username>curl -w "\n" http://172.21.240.1:8080/hello

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset

C:\Users\username>curl -w "\n" http://172.21.251.69:8080/hello

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.21.251.69 port 8080: Connection refused
```

where,

- `192.168.1.6` is the IP address of my Windows host
- `172.21.240.1` is the IP address of the *vEthernet (WSL)* adapter
- `172.21.251.69` is the IP address of the Ubuntu 20.04 running inside WSL2 (obtained by running `ip addr | grep eth0`). I can `ping 172.21.251.69` from `cmd`.

What am I doing wrong? I thought `curl -w "\n" http://localhost:8080/hello` would **just work** from the Windows host.

Winver reports Windows version as *Version 2004 (OS Build 19041.1110)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Quarkus, but my "go to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455770/11810933)" for localhost forwarding not working in WSL is to try a `wsl --shutdown` and, if that works, disable Windows Fast Startup.

But in this case, you also aren't able to access it on the WSL2 instance's eth0 address, so something more *might* be going on. That could also be explained if the Quarkus boilerplate config is just binding to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. You'd need it to bind to `0.0.0.0` in order for both to work.

*Update for others looking at this answer in the future*: Quarkus automatically binding to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` did turn out to be the problem in this case.  From @markvgti's research in the comments, the setting for this is to add `quarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0` to the `application.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the update of NotTheDr01ds answer:

Add `quarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0` to the `application.properties` worked for me